# Cannot rerun compiled script in V8 C++ embedding

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I'm attempting to rerun a V8 script in a given context/scope, but I'm getting a segmentation fault.  If I compile other scripts and run in succession it works.

```
int loadScript(const char * scriptCode) {
  v8::Local<v8::String> source =
    v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, scriptCode,
    v8::NewStringType::kNormal)
    .ToLocalChecked();

  // Compile the source code.
  script =
    v8::Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();

  return 0;
}

std::string executeScript() {
  // Run the script to get the result.
  v8::Local<v8::Value> result = script->Run(context).ToLocalChecked();

  // Convert the result to an UTF8 string and print it.
  v8::String::Utf8Value utf8(isolate, result);

  return std::string(*utf8);
}
```

////

```
sv8i.loadScript("let a = 1; \
    let b = 2; \
    JSON.stringify({a, b}); \
  ");

  printf("%s\n", sv8i.executeScript().c_str());
  printf("%s\n", sv8i.executeScript().c_str());  // Seg fault
```

Result is:

```
    {"a":1,"b":2}
Thread 1 "spirit_v8_test" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x000055555585c9c8 in v8::internal::ScriptContextTable::Lookup(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::ScriptContextTable, v8::internal::String, v8::internal::VariableLookupResult*) ()
    (gdb) backtrace
    #0  0x000055555585c9c8 in v8::internal::ScriptContextTable::Lookup(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::ScriptContextTable, v8::internal::String, v8::internal::VariableLookupResult*) ()
    #1  0x00005555556e3cfc in v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::Invoke(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeParams const&) ()
    #2  0x00005555556e36a6 in v8::internal::Execution::Call(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>*) ()
    #3  0x0000555555651990 in v8::Script::Run(v8::Local<v8::Context>) ()
    #4  0x00005555556444b9 in SpiritV8Interface::executeScript[abi:cxx11]() (this=0x7fffffffe2b0) at ./spirit_bin_src/spirit_v8_interface.cpp:54
    #5  0x00005555556446a9 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe4a8) at ./spirit_bin_src/spirit_v8_interface.cpp:80
```

Why?

Comment: Any details on the error? Like a line number or so?

Comment: This line printf("%s\n", sv8i.executeScript().c_str()); marked with Seg fault

Comment: And the complete error message? Just `Seg Fault`?

Comment: Editted with backtrace in gdb

Comment: And (same) the line before that marked with `// Set fault` does work properly?!

Comment: Yes, runs perfectly.

Comment: I think this is a V8 bug.  If I change the js code, it works.

Comment: Usually the `Seg Fault` error refers to a illegal memory access due to missing pointer or access rights.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that StackOverflow is not a "please debug my code for me" service. In that sense, one could argue that this question should be closed.

That said, there are a few more things that can be said here, and are more generally applicable:

(2) If you do ask for help with a snippet of code, please post a [**complete, reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
In the case at hand, some crucial information is missing, which may well explain what's going wrong: what's the type of `script` and `context`? When and how are they initialized? What are their lifetimes? Are they `v8::Local`s, and if so, where are the HandleScopes governing them? I bet the problem lies somewhere in this area, but unless you post your entire code (complete enough that I could copy-paste it and run it locally if I wanted to), it's hard to be sure.

(3) Once you get past the segfault, you'll encounter another problem: `.ToLocalChecked()` means *"I know this `MaybeLocal` is not empty, and if I'm wrong and it actually *is* empty, then **I want the process to crash**"*. JavaScript is a very exception-happy language, so as a C++ embedder you have to deal with the possibility that pretty much any bit of JS code could throw. That's what `MaybeLocal`s are for: you can check if they contain a value, or whether an exception has prevented a result value from being returned. You can additionally use a `v8::TryCatch` to catch the exception that was thrown, causing the empty `MaybeLocal`.
The fact that changing the JavaScript snippet makes it work is a big hint here: running `let a = 1` twice in the same context will *of course* throw an exception. If you "handle" that with `.ToLocalChecked()`, then you're asking for a crash.

It may help to read V8's [embedder documentation](http://v8.dev/docs/embed), which explains these and many other concepts in more detail. (And while you're at it, maybe some of the StackOverflow introductory documentation as well.)

Comment: Very good point on the ToLocalChecked().  Noticed that this v8::MaybeLocal concept functions a bit like Rust's Option with .unwrap, but wasn't certain of the logic.

Comment: Read the embedder documentation.  It's out of date (the API has moved on) and there are inconsistencies of namespace in the code.  Hard to follow.

Comment: (On your first point, I launched into a Stackoverflow plea because there isn't any documentation)